# connecting logic gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

This is a controller I was going to make to operate a 2 wire LED as a side marker / turn signal light on my off road (so, no need to get bent out of shape about FMVSS and DOT requirements) Jeep. The problem is that it is wired from the factory with a single filament bulb and two powered circuits using a floating ground. The obviously won't work, because you can't reverse polarity through an LED like you can with a filament bulb. I have done the same thing before with some standard automotive diodes and relays, but I wanted a more elegant solution and this is more fun (not to mention this way is actually cheaper and takes up way less space). So, yes this is a complex solution to a simple problem, but I like doing stuff like this and learning along the way.

EDIT - I re-drew the circuit using the XOR gate. will it work properly as designed now?
REVISION - (edited as recommended)

The idea here is that the marker and turn signal functions work normally when used separately, but when the marker is on the turn signal will cause it to "blink" off.

[image: LEDlogic]

I added diodes and capacitors in the power lines after reading the cautions on the product data sheets to do so in order to keep the gates and the relay more stable. They may not be necessary, but for a few bucks it's better safe than sorry.

I just wanted to see if the people on here thought it would function properly the way I have it drawn before I go prototyping it. THANKS!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fngo6b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT #2: here is the original seriously flawed schematic for discussion reference purposes -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmRWcc.png)</sup>

Comment: This seems like a spectacularly complicated way of making a bridge-rectifier out of logic, etc...

Comment: I wouldn't try to power the NAND gate from the output of the OR gate, like you've done. The NAND has input clamping diodes that will pass input voltage to its supply rail when unpowered. Just a big 'no'. Please edit your question with a truth table (TURN&MARKER = 00, 01, 10, 11) showing what you want the circuit to do for all 4 cominbations of input voltage. Then we'll know what problem you're trying to solve. Thanks.

Comment: That makes it clear so, yes, use a bridge rectifier as the others have said. With all that circuit, I thought there was some hidden complication I'd missed :-)

Comment: If you really want to do this with digital logic, then the logic gate you're looking for is an XOR (exclusive or). Its output is high when its input are different, and low when they are the same - just like your truth-table shows.

Comment: Thank you! I will re-draw using that gate. What about the rest of the circuit? Do I need to use higher V rated components (over 16V)? Are the capacitors too large or the diodes too small?

Comment: I edited my original question with the new schematic using the XOR gate. Will this function?

Comment: As you're looking for an exercise in logic and electronics, check out the [Wiki article on Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Digital_logic_gates) and the application of [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) to simplify logical circuits (and Boolean algebraic expressions).

Comment: Yes, thank you. I have studied and taken courses involving logic, but unfortunately there was no actual practical application involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty "brave" to connect (what I think are) 16V (18V abs max) logic chips directly to a 12V automotive supply. Automotive standards call for survival of transients much larger than that. At least you have a diode to prevent negative transients from zapping things.

Please give manufacturer part numbers not distributor numbers.

The NAND will get powered by the protection diodes whenever either input is high.

There is no current limiting- it's not for sure the wimpy little BAV21 diodes will survive charging the 10uF caps, nor is it clear what exactly discharges them.

There should be a series resistor on the SSR LED to limit the current.

---

I agree with @brhans comment- just stick a W04M in there and be done with it.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWnEGm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I'm confused again, there are two "filaments here. I am using a 2 wire LED to serve both functions.

Comment: So do I need to just use higher V rated gates?   I edited my question and added mfc part#s. I dont know what you mean by "NAND will get powered by the protection diodes whenever either input is high". Would you suggest larger diodes or smaller capacitors (1 miro farad?)? Are you saying I need a resistor in the input line to the relay?

Comment: I may not be opposed to using a bridge rectifier, but I'm not seeing how. I have two possible inputs, and a single output. The inputs and the turn signal power and the marker power. The output is a LED light with only two wires (a positive and a negative). I want the output active when either of the inputs is active, but non active when nether is or both are. I do not have two lamps or filaments. I would still like to know what I did wrong in my original design and I may still build it just for funsies if I can figure out what is wrong and why and how to fix it.

Comment: note that the zener won't stop automotive transients. They can be pretty rough. Need MOVs or other TVS's. Many automotive "TVS" circuits simply disconnect when there's a spike, as it's too difficult/expensive to deal with it.

Comment: @tyblu Are you referring to the other circuit? If so, the Zener will do fine because there is 3K in series. It can handle a 10ms surge at 380mA so 3.8kV for 10ms- something else will die first. You are correct that you can't absorb an automotive surge with a Zener so I try to rate the parts to a high enough voltage and then you just have to ride it out and not suppress it directly.

Comment: The XOR gate I used is rated for up to +7VDC. Is that not enough of a cushion? Is there some other form of protection system I should be adding in? @Spehro Pefhany

Comment: **Your original circuit had the gate Vcc connected directly to the 12V vehicle supply through a diode**. Totally unacceptable. The current circuit is still substandard but might survive. The regulator you added is good for 35V abs max. The input protection scheme harms the functionality but should protect the inputs. K?

Comment: It seems like I made you mad. I'm certainly not arguing with you. I'm asking questions because I legitimately want to know the answers and learn. I took your advice about the vehicle 12V system being too much and too unstable for the logic components and that is why I created the second circuit. If you have the time to explain what is substandard about it and how the protection scheme harms the functionality that would be great and I would appreciate it. If any of my responses or comments came off as smart ***ed, snarky, or argumentative, it was a mis-communication on my part. @Spehro Pefhany

Comment: Not at all but it's a bit irritating when the original is changed (rather than added to) which makes answers that referred to it look like total nonsense. I explained that there is no way to discharge those 220n capacitors on the inputs- so the inputs go high and stay high until leakage discharges (or charges) them. The series diodes on the inputs are causing that problem- leave them out.

Comment: I see now I should have left the original schematic. I still have it saved if you think I should put it back up. Am I understanding correctly that you are saying I should remove diodes #1, 2, and 3 but not 4 & 5 (or any of the others)? I was thinking that the capacitors would discharge through the circuit when incoming power was interrupted (basically keeping the circuit powered for a very short time). I'm sure I was wrong, but can you help me understand why? Thank you again for taking your time!

Comment: Zeners aside, the only useful one that I can see is the one in series with the regulator input, and it should be rated at 200V or more. Replace the one in series with the SSR input with a suitable resistor.

Comment: yeah @SpehroPefhany, I was talking about OP's circuit. The zener itself can handle it, but the transient won't be clamped fast enough for those logic gates. They're flimsy. Also the ground plane doesn't have protection (neg spikes) unless we assume it's protected up the line. A FET-controlled input could disconnect the input on a surge, in addition to the zener and cap. Of course, TI kills it here: [link](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva717/snva717.pdf).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - I believe I have made the changes that you recommended. I believe the regulator input diode meets your recommendations if I have read the product sheet correctly it is rated at 250V. I did some research and it lead me to believe that a 1K resistor was proper to protect the diode in the relay, is that correct? If you could help me understand where my misunderstanding was about the caps discharging forward through the circuit was I would appreciate it. Is there no concern about them back feeding into the switch providing the turn and marker signals? Thank you!

Comment: @tyblu - can you elaborate? It sounds like you are talking about spikes from the automotive 12V system causing damage? On the ground protection - it will be grounded to a chassis ground to a lug that already has a braided strap going to the PDC negative. Are you talking about something as simple as a diode in the ground line on the board? thank you

Comment: I went ahead and ordered these components and will prototype and test this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think we can simplify your schematic a little:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzMwS2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The required XOR (exclusive OR) function is performed by the existing relay / switch logic on the left. Since lamp polarity reverses in operation a rectifier is required when converting to LED.*

Comment: Yes, I know it is a complicated solution to simple problem. I am mostly wanting to do it this way to practice and learn (re-learn) logic circuits and for an excuse to build a PCB with SMD components. What I don't understand is why the two above circuits have two "lamps". Tis circuit is for one light on one side of the vehicle to operate as a marker and a turn signal and will be duplicated on both sides of the vehicle. And, yes the LEDs are designed for 12V automotive lighting applications.

Comment: The lamps represent the existing vehicle lamps on that side of the vehicle.

Comment: That is not what I am trying to do. I am replacing 1 lamp (single filament bulb) with a sigle LED. I thought I explained pertty explicitly in my question, maybe I was unclear.

Comment: Your question is far from clear, I'm afraid. If you had drawn a schematic of the existing system it would have been much clearer.  I've updated my answer. Anything more complex would be madness.

Comment: When I get to work tomorrow I'll be happy to post the schematics of the original circuit. I will also post the circuit I built on the other Jeep. If I knew how my question was unclear I would clear it up. I would seriously also like to know what I did wrong that would kame my original circuit not work. This is a project or experiment for learning and trying new things just as much as it is a solution to a problem. Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: I didn't post the OEM schematics because it seems like someone sees what I'm trying to do here. The relay method I used before used two relays and two diodes. Since I can't insert schematics in a comment I didn't want to clutter up my question with that. It worked, but I'm wanting to do this a different way to use less space and to try something new and learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you would prefer a more robust circuit here is one that does not use any fragile CMOS chips and hence does not require much protection. D2/D3/R1/R2/Q1/Q2 are a discrete exclusive-OR gate driving the power MOSFET, much as @transistor's answer. The zener D1 protects the MOSFET gate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKstbh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That's odd, going from recommending a bridge rectifier to all this circuitry - what's the benefit over a bridge rectifier? No disrespect but was about to downvote it.

Comment: A bit less voltage drop.. it's just a kind of fun exercise and a break from the current project with hundreds and hundreds of components.

Comment: I though it was you couldn't resist, it's a fun one to have a crack at :-) But I'll have to downvote so it's not mistaken as a plausible answer in the long run.

Comment: Why are their two "lamps"?

Comment: @TonyM Gotta do what you gotta do ;-) - I think it's a good illustration of a 'complete' solution rather than a 'outline' that doesn't have protection etc.

Comment: @LsD the original lamps- they were shown in another answer but deleted. I'm not positive they were accurately represented so caveat emptor.

Comment: +1 to any feasible suggestions with discretes, in the spirit of AoE :)